# getting this Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters: mapper_parsing_exception while running below query in Kibana Console

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

extracted this query from internet

```
PUT developer
{
  "mappings": {
    "developer": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "skills": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "language": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "level": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- facing this error while running this query in kibana console

```
"caused_by" : {
      "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [developer : {properties={skills={type=object, properties={level={type=keyword}, language={type=keyword}}}, name={type=text}}}]"
    }
```

- Version used

  - Kibana 7.9.3
  - Elastic Search 7.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `developer` type (between `mappings` and `properties`), as types [have been deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html):

```
  PUT developer
  {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "skills": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "language": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "level": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```